# Phonon VideoWidget playback from updated QBuffer

Tags: qt, phonon

I'm trying to create a video player that can decrypt video data in memory and play it without ever storing the decrypted data on the hard drive. I'm using the Qt Framework with the Video Widget and a QBuffer. I decrypt the first segment of the video and store it in a QBuffer and start playback. This works but after setCurrentSource is called, all data written to the QBuffer is ignored.

I believe this has to do with the different backends. Is it possible to achieve playback directly from memory in Qt (pyQt) and if not are there any alternatives?

```
QFile file ("/Users/user/video.mov");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QByteArray array1;
QByteArray array2;
QBuffer *playbackBuffer = new QBuffer();
playbackBuffer->open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);

array1 = file.read(10000000);
array2 = file.read(10000000);

playbackBuffer->write(array1);

videoMedia->setCurrentSource(playbackBuffer);
videoOutput->play();
playbackBuffer->write(array2);
```